# highcharts-react Gantt: get mouse coordinates from mouse-over

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using the official highcharts wrapper for react to generate a Gantt chart.
I'm trying to get the mouse coordinates from a mouse-over event and use them for a custom tooltip, but the coordinates are imprecise.

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c5mivs

The event returns plotX and plotY which as far as I understand are supposed to be the mouse coordinates. It also return an array called tooltipPos which I'm guessing are the coordinates for the native tooltip.

Both places the tooltip in the wrong place. Is there an offset that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinates `plotX` and `plotY` are in relation to plot area. If you want to have the relation to chart container, you need to add `plotLeft` and `plotTop` values:

```
handleTooltip = (event) => {
  const chart = event.target.series.chart;

  this.setState({
    isVisible: true,
    tooltipPosX: chart.plotLeft + event.target.tooltipPos[0],
    tooltipPosY: chart.plotTop + event.target.tooltipPos[1]
  })
};
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jfehmb?file=index.js